# What is the network overhead for RewardedVideoAd.loadAd()?

Tags: android, admob

What is the network overhead when calling `RewardedVideoAd.loadAd()`?

I have a game in which players are occasionally offered rewarded videos. Most players, however, choose to play entirely without rewarded ads.

For this reason, I want to be careful about network overheads. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video) recommend calling `loadAd()` "as soon as possible", eg on `onCreate`.

How wasteful is this if the user never chooses a rewarded ad? Does it for example start pre-caching an entire video, or does it just load some lightweight metadata?

The ultimate question I'm trying to answer is, should I in my case only call `loadAd()` when the user chooses a rewarded ad, despite the docs' recommendations? I appreciate that this will cause a delay before the ad is displayed, but that may be a necessary evil for a better UX for most other players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the call to load an ad, AdMob fetches an ad and begins caching its video asset. This behavior is common to every ad network I've seen.

In some network conditions, it can take a long time to load a video file, so I wouldn't recommend forcing users to wait while one loads, even if they've indicated they're willing to watch it. If you're particularly concerned about network overhead (and good on you for considering that aspect of the user experience), I would recommend giving the user a freebie reward the first time they indicate they're willing to watch an ad, and then loading an ad for the next round.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.